# How to use TailwindCSS with Material UI?

Tags: next.js, material-ui

I am using Next.js with Material UI. I am having troubles with using Tailwind with MUI. I've been following [this](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css) guide but it still doesn't work. The file loads but the classes just don't apply. If someone could help, that would be wonderful!

My Tailwind Config

```
    module.exports = {
  important: "#__next",
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

My _app.js

```
//import '../styles/globals.css'

//function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
//  return <Component {...pageProps} />
//}

//export default MyApp

import '../styles/edit.css';
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider, StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import { CacheProvider } from '@emotion/react';
import theme from '../config/themeConfig';
import createEmotionCache from '../functions/createEmotionCache';
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
//import '../styles/tailwind.css';


// Client-side cache, shared for the whole session of the user in the browser.
const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache();

export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;

  return (
      <Layout>
          <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
        <Head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" />
        </Head>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
                {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
                <CssBaseline />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </StyledEngineProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
      </Layout>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  emotionCache: PropTypes.object,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: hi, does the browser should the stylesheet as loaded?

Comment: Yes it does, I try it via importing it and adding it as a link in the html header

Comment: what is your tailwind config and _app.js?

Comment: Edited it with my code

Comment: Note that you are using an "Emotion cache". See ["you need to add the prepend option"](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css). Also dialogs might not be descendants of `#__next`. I used `body` instead (I don't know if that is fine, but it seems to work).

Comment: I have prepend enabled. So I replace #__next with body?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't follow the guide ( https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/interoperability/#tailwind-css ) correctly.

In your `tailwind.config.js` file you need to set the `corePlugins` parameter to disable the `preflight` CSS. The preflight CSS is overriding some of the styles of MUI.